# Pymongo $Unset doesn't do anything

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, pymongo

I'm using pymongo and flask to put information about which desktops a person owns from a database onto a webpage in a table. Simple enough. But I have a button which is supposed to remove a desktop from the database using $pull.

The mongo document looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55c4a89a80071a0ef20e4df1"),
    "Hostname" : "XXXXXXXXX",
    "BUILD OS" : "WINDOWS 7 ENTERPRISE",
    "Current User" : "CAMPELK",
    "Primary User" : "CAMPELK",
    "Location" : "XXXXX",
    "Model" : "vmware inc. vmware virtual platform",
    "BUILD Version Full" : "5.1.00.00",
    "BUILD Version" : 5.1,
   }
```

(I've had to censor some data due to workplace rules)
The name of the desktop model is returned from a drop down menu form as a string like this:

```
@app.route('/contact_desktop', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def contact2():
    form1= name_search()
    name = form1.name.data
    choices = DI.make_dictionary()
    form2 = ContactFormDesktop()
    models = DI.return_model(name)
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        DI.remove_give_back_desktop(models, form2.choose_desktop.data, name)
        return render_template('thanks.html', thing = "desktop")
```

And the remove_give_back_desktop() method is supposed to remove the field which matches the model string returned by the form:

```
def return_model(name):
    models = list()
    for entry in db.names.find({}):
            model = entry["models"]
            models.append(model)
    return models


def remove_give_back_desktop(model1, model2, name):
    for entry in model1:
            if entry == model2:
                    db.desktops.update_one({"Current User":name, "Model": entry},{"$unset":{"Model":""}})
```

However, nothing is happening when I click the button in the html page, no errors are thrown and the code runs just fine otherwise, but the field that was supposed to be removed is still there.

The update $unset method works in the mongo terminal when I manually insert the name and model, so is my syntax wrong for pymongo or is there a deeper problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Function inputs are "model1" and "model2". Your query calls "model", which is undefined and therefore does not match anything,

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo from trying to get the whitespace right. Edited my question, the above problem still stands

Comment: in the meantime, you could trigger the verbose log of mongodb to see what the exact operation towards the db.

Comment: I still would strongly suggest that you look at your inputs and do some logging. The query not matching anything is the most likely explanation here. No you have not found a bug.

Comment: Try this:
db.desktops.update_one({"Current User":name, "Model": entry},{"$unset":{"Model":1}})